# Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 32

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I am using s3 source connector i am trying to import data from s3 to auto created topic. i am using aws msk cluster.

```
[Worker-001d22b042f681d7a] [2023-10-21 17:49:44,127] WARN [source-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-source-connector-0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {source-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1119)
[Worker-001d22b042f681d7a] [2023-10-21 17:49:44,127] INFO [source-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-source-connector-0] Cluster ID: J4cTke2TRmOSsoYBO5uZdA (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:279)
[Worker-001d22b042f681d7a] [2023-10-21 17:49:44,478] WARN [source-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-source-connector-0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {source-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1119)
[Worker-001d22b042f681d7a] [2023-10-21 17:49:44,581] WARN [source-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-source-connector-0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {source-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1119)
```

approach s3 source connector

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector
useAccelerateMode=true
s3.region=us-east-1
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=b-4.sink.2uql3y.c4.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:90921.amazonaws.com:9092
auto.create.topics.enable=true
flush.size=7
schema.compatibility=NONE
tasks.max=2
topics=target-topic
pathStyleAccess=true
schema.enable=false
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
aws.region=us-east-1
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
errors.log.enable=true
s3.bucket.name=bucket-name
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

after creating default topic _confluent-command i received msg from s3 to new auto created topic.

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic _confluent-command --consumer.config /home/ec2-user/kafka_2.12-3.5.1/config/consumer.properties --from-beginning --bootstrap-server <bootstrap-server>
```

```
�
�eyJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJpc3MiOiJDb25mbHVlbnQiLCJhdWQiOiJ0cmlhbCIsImV4cCI6MTcwMDUwNTg3OCwianRpIjoiamoySWFWQTV6ckVjSG94ZUw5X1dsUSIsImlhdCI6MTY5NzkxMzg3NywibmJmIjoxNjk3OTEzNzU3LCJzdWIiOiJDb25mbHVlbnQgRW50ZXJwcmlzZSIsIm1vbml0b3JpbmciOnRydWUsImxpY2Vuc2VUeXBlIjoidHJpYWwifQ.
```

Comment: I am using all setup through aws console.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the _confluent-command topic is Protobuf serialized and is not human readable. Only Confluent maintains the Protobuf schema for reading that data, to ensure their licensing is not bypassed

If you want to read your S3 data, look at your config

```
topics=target-topic
```

Besides this, your real error message says **`source-topic`** doesn't exist, or there's no healthy partitions for it

```
source-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION
```

Comment: target-topic is available but when i run s3 source connector its automictically created topic  _confluent-command

Comment: Yes, because that connector requires a license; it's not free to use after 30 days. You're not getting any error about it, and as answered, it's not going to be readable in the terminal. What's your question?

Comment: I am using trial version.

Comment: Sure. As answered, you cannot read the _confluent-command topic. So, again, what is your question? Your error says `source-topic` does not exist, so create **that**

Comment: I am facing when I create source connector confluent data not backup from s3 to msk topic I try so many thing but facing error which I mentioned in question.

Comment: And your question says that `source-topic` doesn't exist, so I answered to create that topic. You'll need to provide more logs after you have fixed this

Comment: source-topic is which i was stored data from msk to s3 using confluent sink connector i want to restore data from s3 to msk using confluent source connector and i want to restore data (s3 to msk) in my new topic target-topic.

Comment: Without seeing more logs, I cannot help you further, sorry